# Numerically solving a system of non-homogenous linear ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm unsure how to approach numerically modeling the following system of ODEs:
\begin{align}
0&=-a \frac{dT_1(t)}{dt} +bT_2 +c T_1 -K(t)\tag1
\\[.3em]
0&=-a \frac{dT_2(t)}{dt} +b(T_3-T_1) + c (T_2-T_4)\tag2
\\[.3em]
0&=-a \frac{dT_3(t)}{dt} -bT_1 +c (T_3 -T_5)\tag3
\\[.3em]
0 &= -d(K(t)-T_4)+c(T_1-K(t)+(T_2-T_4)/2)\tag4
\\[.8em]
0 &= -d(T_4-T_5)+c(T_2-T_4)/2+c(T_3-T_5)\tag5
\end{align}
where $K(t)$ is an array of discrete values. There are five variables that are functions of time. Initial conditions are $T_{1,2,3,4,5}(0)=300$. I initially tried to follow [this tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/voigtlab/BP205/Notes/BP205_Matlab_slides.pdf) for the ODE solver functions in MATLAB, but it became clear that wasn't going to work because this problem is non-homogenous, and because the last two equations cannot be put into the required form of $dy_4/dt =\alpha y_4(t) ...$ unless a $dy_1/dt$ is added to the right side, which isn't permissible in the code syntax. The next thing I attempted was to solve the system of equations with the time derivatives as variables (total of 8 variables) at every time step, but I don't know how I would account for the initial conditions.

Comment: It is pointless to set initial values for $T_4$ and $T_5$. In fact, if the last two equations hold for $t=0$, setting initial conditions may lead to an impossible problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use equation (4) to write $T_4$ in terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$ and equation (5) to write $T_5$ in terms of $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$. Substituting back in equations (1), (2), (3), you have a system of three ordinary differential equations that can be handled by matlab.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set $S_4=K-T_4$ and $S_5=T_4-T_5$ and insert $T_4=K-S_4$ and $T_5=T_4-S_5=K-S_4-S_5$ in the non-derivative terms.

Do not forget to use interpolation to compute values of $K(t)$ at arbitrary times $t$.